# How to customize django auth decorator with urls.py?

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have several urls defined:

```
url(r'^board/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='recruit/board.html'), name='recruit_board'),
url(r'^job/$', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='recruit/job_detail.html')), name='job_detail'),
url(r'^company/$', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='recruit/company_detail.html')), name='company_detail'),
```

... and users I designed have two account types: *A* or *B*.

The "job" url can only be accessed by users with an *A* account type, and the "company" url can only be viewed by *B* account type users. If users try to access a wrong url, it will be redirected to the "board" url.

I have used the *login_required* decorator, and I know about *user_passes_test*, but I don't know how to go on from here. Can I write a new decorator that works just like *login_required* and get what I want?

Comment: How are your "account types" implemented? Are you leveraging [Django's Permissions and Authorization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) system?

Comment: @Chris No, _account types_ and other user-related characteristics are defined in a new Model named Profile, related to the User object.

Comment: @KirChou How can I write this _is_company_ decorator? And what can I do to redirect it to the "board" url? Could you be a little bit more specific? Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think [group_required decorator](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1703/) is match for your purpose.

I assume you have three group `['admin', 'job', 'company']`, you can write the code like this. Since `group_required` has checked `is_authenticated`, you do not need `login_required` anymore.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def group_required(*group_names):
    """Requires user membership in at least one of the groups passed in."""
    def in_groups(u):
        if u.is_authenticated():
            if bool(u.groups.filter(name__in=group_names)) | u.is_superuser:
                return True
        return False
    return user_passes_test(in_groups)

url(r'^board/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='recruit/board.html'), name='recruit_board'),
url(r'^job/$', group_required(['admin', 'job'])(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='recruit/job_detail.html')), name='job_detail'),
url(r'^company/$', group_required(['admin', 'company'])(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='recruit/company_detail.html')), name='company_detail'),
```